# Can I see SSL Certificate from browser developer tools

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am learning SSL certificates and confused a bit. When I send a request to a secured https web site, the site sends me a certificate with response. I can see the certificate info when clicked pedlock icon. Can I see the certificate file via developer tools(F12) network on browser?

Comment: Certificate Flow ? What do you mean ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, open the developer tools, and click on the Security tab.  Then click "Overview on the left" > View Certificate.

Chrome example: click the Lock Icon next to the address bar > Certificate

[image: Security Settings]

Comment: This works in Edge Chromium as well.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot see that via developer tools. But you can try this link https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/en_US to locate the certificate file on each specific website

Comment: This is not correct. You can absolutely see the certificate from the Security tab as the answer from JBaczuk states.

Answer (score -1):

***No*** you cannot see the certificate from the browser development tools As far as what i have seen , Pls correct me if i am wrong] .

But you can take a tcpdump and analyse it using wireshark and see the certificate being sent to the client.